# Using aria-describedby="" on a div?

Tags: html, wai-aria

Is it possible to use the aria-describedby attribute on a div? I've seen that implemented on buttons and input elements, but not on span or div. Any idea?

I tried it and used ChromeVox and MacOS Voice Over, but I got no response or description.

Best Regards!

Sy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not, it should work with `div`'s too http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-describedby

Comment: Thx for the hint user2035819. It just bugged me, because I got no response or description when using ChromeVox or Voice Over. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Aria-describedby is designed to work with interactive elements like links, buttons, and form fields. It usually doesn't work with static elements like divs and spans unless you add a role to it.

However, in my testing, its support among browsers and screen readers is inconsistent at best and nonexistent in some, especially when it comes to form fields. With forms, I avoid it altogether and use other solutions like aria-labelledby (which has much stronger support).

Webaim, who I greatly respect, provides more info on advanced form controls and labeling: https://webaim.org/techniques/forms/advanced